# Can I add related data with a relationship or multiselect field

Tags: relationships

Simple Example:  I have one Chanel "Walks" and another "Walk Variations".  I know I can create walk variations and then have a relationship field in Walks to select the correct Walk Variations.  What I would like to be able to do is create a walk and then on the same form add multiple walk variations.

Similarly, with a multi-select field is there a way to add an option from the current channel, rather than having to do that separately?

Is that possible? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why not to use GRID or Fluid field in EE4?

Comment: I think Walk Variations needs to be it's own channel as it will have Walk Segments  as a child.  I'm new to EE so perhaps I'm thinking about it incorrectly?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if while selecting related entries from an existing entry, that you be able to add new entries to that list of related content at the same time? If so, no you cannot do that from the same view as they exist in different channels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mufi is right.
For EE2 and EE3 use [Grid](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html) and for EE4 use [Fluid](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/fluid.html#grid-fields)

Comment: I'm not sure you are answering the specific question. I believe the question is about relationships and authoring new relationship entries while selecting them from another channel entry.